# ЧПУ .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Игрался с htaccess на сайте, но так и не смог добиться желаемого.

Есть ссылка вида

http://site.com/item?id=40231079410#63478535852

Хотелось бы ее привести к виду

http://site.com/item/40231079410

Или

http://site.com/item/40231079410#63478535852

http://site.com/item/40231079410/63478535852

Comment: лучше в самом движке роутер организуйте, и все запросы к несуществующим файлам отправляйте на index.php

Comment: `http://site.com/item/40231079410#63478535852`

работать не будет никогда, потому-что то, что после # не передается на сервер.

Comment: Печаль беда. И что делать теперь?

Comment: @eicto, в чём проблема? Сервер получит и обработает `http://site.com/item/40231079410`,а `#63478535852` так и останется только в браузере. В исходном варианте оно ведь тоже на сервер не передаётся.

Comment: @mrclon, а можете помочь, как сделать ссылку такого вида?

Comment: @mrclon, вроде-бы @Ануар хочет:

из http://site.com/item/40231079410#63478535852 сделать http://site.com/item/40231079410/63478535852

Comment: @eicto, как я понял он хочет из

http://site.com/item?id=40231079410#63478535852

сделать
http://site.com/item/40231079410 или http://site.com/item/40231079410#63478535852 или http://site.com/item/40231079410/63478535852

Последний вариант невозможен, первые два — возможны.